# Trouble connecting to Orbbec Persee by USB from Windows 7

Tags: windows, usb, openni, motion-detection, orbbec

*(This is a direct duplicate of [the post I've made on Orbbec's 3DClub forums](https://3dclub.orbbec3d.com/t/trouble-connecting-to-persee-by-usb-from-windows-7/1659/1).)*

I've got an [Orbbec Persee Development Kit](https://orbbec3d.com/product-persee/) here and it's happily connected to my TV, booted up and running ok — I played the game Ocean a little and it's working fine.

I've installed [the Orbbec Sensor Driver for Windows](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyw9pcfrf0zgck1/Driver_Windows.zip?dl=0) from [orbbec3d.com/develop](https://orbbec3d.com/develop/) and read the [instruction manual](https://3dclub.orbbec3d.com/t/persee-instruction-manual/640/8). I already have OpenNI, Nuitrack and Unity installed.

When I plug the Persee into my Windows 7 laptop by USB, Windows looks for drivers for an "[ADB Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_software_development#ADB)" and fails:

[image: Screenshot of Windows "Driver Software Installation" dialog showing "Installing device driver software" for "ADB Interface" at the stage of "Searching Windows Update..."]
[image: Screenshot of the Device Manager properties dialog reading "The drivers for this device are not installed"]

I am at a loss as to how I can get Windows to recognise the Persee. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Comment: It doesn't look like the drivers are being recognized. What were the steps you took to install the drivers? Did you use `SensorDriver_V4.3.0.4.exe`? Have you tried installing it manually via the "Update Driver" button and the files in "Manual Installation Guide" folder? Did you have any problems following the "Astra Series Depth Driver Manual Installation Guide for Windows.pdf", and if so, at which step?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install windows 8 or windows 10. It does not work properly with windows 7.

Comment: That's for the Astra SDK. The requirements for the driver list Windows 7.